# How can I stop a jQuery function on hover and start on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a jQuery function that is running on **mousemove** event. Actually, I have to separate image one is main image and one shadow image. I am using **mousemove** event to reflect the shadow image. Everything is working fine but I want to stop the **mousemove** event when I will hover over the main image. Again It will run when I will release the mouse form the image. How can I get that. Here is link - http://zakirinfo.com/mouse/

HTML

```
<div style="width:100%">
<img id="shadow-img" style="position:absolute;"src="./assets/img/slsshadow.jpg"></img>
<img id="center-img" style="position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;margin-left:-204px;margin-top:-204px" src="./assets/img/slslogo.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
(function() {
    var shadowImg = document.getElementById('shadow-img');
    var centerImg = document.getElementById('center-img');
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        var center = {
            x : centerImg.getBoundingClientRect().left + 204,
            y : centerImg.getBoundingClientRect().top
        };
        console.log(center);
        var shadowPos = {
            x : (1.8 * center.x) - event.pageX,
            y : (2.2 * center.y) - event.pageY,
        };

        shadowImg.style.transform = 'translate(' + shadowPos.x + 'px,' + shadowPos.y +'px)';
    };
})();
```

Comment: so add a mouseeneter and mouseleave events to the image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the working code (if i understood you correctly):

```
(function() {
    var shadowImg = document.getElementById('shadow-img');
    var centerImg = document.getElementById('center-img');
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    centerImg.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    });
    centerImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    });
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        var center = {
            x : centerImg.getBoundingClientRect().left + 204,
            y : centerImg.getBoundingClientRect().top
        };
        console.log(center);
        var shadowPos = {
            x : (1.8 * center.x) - event.pageX,
            y : (2.2 * center.y) - event.pageY,
        };

        shadowImg.style.transform = 'translate(' + shadowPos.x + 'px,' + shadowPos.y +'px)';
    };
})();
```

HTML is unchanged. Also here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wbkdrdpk/2/

Explanation:

First of all I use addEventListener to assign the events.

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
```

This does pretty much the same as your line but it has the advantage that you can call the `removeEventListener` function to remove the handler

Now I add two event listener to the image to remove and re-add the move handler:

```
centerImg.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
     document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
});
centerImg.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
     document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
});
```

pretty simple stuff.

Edit: i removed all jquery code since you don't actually use jquery even though you tagged your question with "jquery". I removed the tag too since it's misleading ;)

Comment: It's working. But can I center the shadow image under the main image?

Comment: of course, you just have to program it :D. you already use the clientRect of centerImg for you translation of the shadow. shouldn't be a problem to use the coordinates in the mouseenter handler to center it under it

Comment: Will you please share it?

Comment: Will you please pay me? because im not gonna do your work for you. you have everything you need to do it already in your code

Comment: i just updated the code. i thought you were using jquery since you added the tag to the question. but after looking at your site i saw that you dont use it. the code now doesnt require jquery and should work for sure